# node.js 0.4.0 not serving files to external IPs

Tags: web-server, nginx, firewall, linux

When I run the following script

```
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
```

by doing:

> node hello.js &
>
> curl localhost

I get:

```
Hello World
```

But when I try to access this page from my PC (which is not the same computer as this server), it gives me a 'this webpage can not be found' error. This can't be a problem with the firewall because I can run nginx on port 80 just fine.

Comment: Still running on 127.0.0.1?  That IP is local to the machine and not the local network.

Comment: whoops you are right :(.

Answer (score 3):

You told the server to listen on 127.0.0.1 and this is a internal ip of host 1

which is not reachable from outside: tell your server to listen to 0.0.0.0 and then it works

Answer (score 1):

Change the 127.0.0.1 to your external IP. Thank you to alister bulman.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to mark your own answer as accepted, if it solves the problem. You won't get rep for it, but others will upvote if it works for them.

Comment: better - mark an answer as the solution! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Still running on 127.0.0.1? That IP is local to the machine and not the local network.  You need a network IP address.